# Override community plugin model - Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, overrides, invoice

Hi guys I have a plugin that I need to amend!

The file I need to change is:
/app/code/local/Magestore/Pdfinvoiceplus/Model/Sales/Order/Invoice.php

Here are my plugin files:

/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_InvoiceEmail>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Company_InvoiceEmail>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <invoiceemail>
                <class>Company_InvoiceEmail_Model</class>
            </invoiceemail>
            <magestore_pdfinvoiceplus>
                <rewrite>
                     <sales_order_invoice>Company_InvoiceEmail_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice</sales_order_invoice>
                 </rewrite>
             </magestore_pdfinvoiceplus>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

/app/code/local/Company/InvoiceEmail/Model/Sales/Order/Invoice.php

```
class Company_InvoiceEmail_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice extends Magestore_Pdfinvoiceplus_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice
{
...
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction as to why my module isn't overriding this class?

Thanks!

EDIT Original plugin snippet:

```
<global>
        <models>
            <pdfinvoiceplus>
                <class>Magestore_Pdfinvoiceplus_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>pdfinvoiceplus_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </pdfinvoiceplus>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order>Magestore_Pdfinvoiceplus_Model_Sales_Order</order>
                    <order_invoice>Magestore_Pdfinvoiceplus_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice</order_invoice>
                    <order_creditmemo>Magestore_Pdfinvoiceplus_Model_Sales_Order_Creditmemo</order_creditmemo>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Did you add the dependency to the module you're overriding in your module's setting XML? (app/etc/modules/Company_InvoiceEmail.xml)

Comment: add `/app/code/local/Magestore/Pdfinvoiceplus/etc/confix.xml` code

Comment: @AlexDinca I didn't, what should I be adding exactly?

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood check updated answer

Comment: @KiwisTasteGood how is the model prefix defined in the Magestore Pdfinvoiceplus XML? Can you please paste it `(app/code/community/Magestore/Pdfinvoiceplus/etc/config.xml)`?

Comment: @AlexDinca I have added in some of the config, was this the bit you needed to see?

Comment: Yes, that's what we needed. Did you try to add module dependency? (see the edited answer below)

Comment: @AlexDinca yes I added that, if I change the <pdfinvoiceplus> node to <sales> it overrides the core fine?

Comment: Yes, it will override the core file, but in that case both the modules will do that, and only one rewrite will be applied. That's why your first choice was good. You need to rewrite Pdfinvoiceplus if you want to keep it's functionality

Comment: @AlexDinca I understand but using pdfinvoiceplus does not seem to override, I'm stumped!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK You have to write below way to rewrite this module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Company_InvoiceEmail>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </Company_InvoiceEmail>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <invoiceemail>
            <class>Company_InvoiceEmail_Model</class>
        </invoiceemail>
        <pdfinvoiceplus><!--Change this node-->
            <rewrite>
                 <sales_order_invoice>Company_InvoiceEmail_Model_Sales_Order_Invoice</sales_order_invoice>
             </rewrite>
         </pdfinvoiceplus>
    </models>
</global>
</config>
```

create a new file in `etc\modules` file name would be `Company_InvoiceEmail.xml`

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_InvoiceEmail>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Magestore_Pdfinvoiceplus/>
            </depends>
        </Company_InvoiceEmail>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work